Sp_rename vs partiton switching to prevent SCH M from blocking select queries during an on-going select
I'm using sp_rename as final step of my ETL stored procedure process to switch the name of staging and final tables.
As this operation takes a SCH M locks, I'm faced with following scenario.
Say a long running SELECT query is running on the FINALTABLE, and at this point the stored procedure is also invoked and it has reached the sp_rename statement, then any other SELECT queries on FINALTABLE get blocked.
I understand this is because the select queries (SCH S) get queued up behind the sp_rename (SCH M).
I'm reading about ways to handle this and the solution seems to be to use the partition switching with wait at low priority syntax that helps to kill the ongoing SELECT or the ALTER TABLE query after a certain duration. However, the first step to partion switching is to truncate the final table which also takes the SCH M lock on the final table, and there's no way to use wait at low priority on the truncate statement. Thus during an on going long select query, and when the SP is invoked causing the truncate statement to run, at this point the truncate is blocked as it needs the SCH M locks, and thus it blocks all subsequent select queries from other sessions.
So I'm trying to understand how exactly is partition switching better compared to using sp_rename in this aspect to prevent the scenario explained above.

In a transaction, you can switch the final table out to an additional empty staging table instead of truncating it.  When that completes you own the Sch-M lock, and switching the staging table in will succeed.
And the first switch can wait at low priority so new SELECT queries are not blocked.
Alternatively you can use RCSI and upsert the final table, removing the need for any Sch-M locks.

Ok so you're saying have a 3rd table say called EMPTYTEMP. Then switch FINAL with EMPTYTEMP, then switch STAGING WITH FINAL

Yes.  Then truncate EMPTYTEMP, or keep it around in case you need to revert FINAL.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to create that 3rd table?

AFAIK, no. There is not.  And it's still not great, as you have to wait for a gap in the SELECT queries or make some of them fail.  So avoiding DDL for this is still better, unless you really are rewriting a majority of the table.
